# How can I format and replace text using only CSS?

Tags: css

This is a vending machine, and I'm being tasked with changing the format of the text.
But the problem is that this vending machine has only CSS customization options.

The requirement is to change this text from `4hr` to `4 HOURS`.
And change the `EXP` to `EXPIRATION`.

So the sample expected output below should be `EXPIRATION: 4 HOURS` and replace the `EXP: 4hr`

Here is the structure of the HTML when I inspect it.

```
<span id="time-elapsed">
  <i>...icon here</i>
  EXP: 4hr
</span>
```

---

> "4hr" is dynamic - the only static is the "hr". Format is "(n)hr"

<sub>I am aware that this could be done by just using [vanilla JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software).</sub>

Comment: Direct text changes like that are not possible. However you can add pseudo elements and set the content to the new text you want.

Comment: yeah. thats what I thinking. hmm..

Comment: @PotatoFleet is right. The problem is that the dynamic text (4) cannot be changed by CSS alone, and the CSS would only be able to act on the elements provided.

Comment: what is the reason for determining whether the format should be short or long? because if just according to a mood it can't be achievable...

Comment: @MisterJojo this is for UX. This mostly to highlight the information and make it more obvious because most of the end users overlooked this information and end up complaining their services suddenly expired.

Comment: maybe but I don't see how this can affect the technical method to use to display this information

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
#time-elapsed:after {
    content: 'whatever you want to add';
}
```